# How to pass data from the response headers to the ApolloProvider with SSR?

Tags: apollo, next.js

I work with an application built with Nextjs and Apollo. I receive a token into the Graphql response headers. I can read this token on the server side and I need to pass it to the Apollo Provider on the client side.

```js
cache.writeData({
    data: {
        isLoggedIn: false
    }
});

const afterwareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {  
    return forward(operation).map(response => {
        const context = operation.getContext();
        const {
            response: { headers },
        } = context;

        if (headers) {
            const authorization = headers.get('authorization');

            if (authorization) {
                console.log(authorization);
                // what to do next? I need somehow set isLoggedIn to true...
            }
        }
        return response;
    });
});

const link = ApolloLink.from([
    afterwareLink,
    new RetryLink(),
    httpLink
]);

const client = new ApolloClient({  
    link,
    cache
});

function App({ children }){
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            {children}
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
}
```

I have tried to set the context inside de ApolloLink:

```js
    operation.setContext({ isLoggedIn: true });
```

I can't write directly on the cache because the page is rendered on the server side.